# Is this an increasing sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

From this beginning of [this](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Emboyle/courses/410f12/liminf.pdf) document -

> Let $(c_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers.
>
> Deﬁne $a_n = \inf\{c_k : k ≥ n\}$
>
> The sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded and increasing so it has a limit $a$.

**Question**

This does not seem to be true to me as $(c_n)$ could be a constant sequence and hence $a_{n+1} = a_n$ for all $n$. I.e. $a_{n+1} > a_n$ for all $n$ is false. So is the document incorrect?

Comment: Increasing can mean "increasing, but not necessarily strictly increasing", in fact I think that is the most common use of the word.

Comment: I'm not sure what the most common use is, @GitGud, so I have a tendency to use "nondecreasing" and "strictly increasing" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @DanielFischer I really hate 'nondecreasing', just recently I couldn't understand something because of the use of that word. I interpreted it as it being false that the function is decreasing. In my native language we have a term for 'nondecreasing' which roughly translates to 'increasing in the broader sense'. It's very useful. I'm biased towards thinking that 'increasing' is more common for not being strict because of order theory, I guess.

Comment: @GitGud, 'nondecreasing' (or, as I would spell it, 'non-decreasing') is the perfect word in English for 'increasing, but not necessarily strictly'. You should learn to love it.

Comment: @TonyK How is it perfect if it contradicts the meaning of the contraction of 'non' with 'decreasing'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think GitGud is right.

Consider JC Burkill, [A First Course in Mathematical Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521294681) (1962), page 31 :

> **Definition**. If $s_{n+1} \ge s_n$ for all values of $n$ we call $s_n$ *increasing*.
>
> It is useful to regard increase in the wide sense, allowing the possibility of equality at any of the steps from $n$ to $n+1$. If $s_{n+1} > s_n$ for all $n$, we call $s_n$ *strictly increasing*.

Then see page 32 :

> *A bounded increasing sequence tends to a limit*.